# XenApp 5.0 Database Connection controlled Interrupt

Tags: windows, database, citrix

we have to migrate our single-server Database system.
This database is used for Citrix xenApp. Is it possible to stop the database for 1 hour but keep our Citrix Farm online?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Citrix forum [article](http://forums.citrix.com/message.jspa?messageID=1390563), and I believe this is correct,

> Yes it should be working just fine for
>   a while without the datastore. The
>   servers have the local host cache
>   which contain parts of the datastore.
>   There is no real time limit for how
>   long the datastore can be unavailable
>   anymore. Of course you will not be
>   able to make any changes to the farm.